# Child process not receiving message

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not sure what is happening here, but when I use fork to start the following process, my main process outputs `Child process " + cid + " running`, but when I try to send a message to the child `"Child process " + data` doesn't output. I am not sure why either.

Here is the child process:

```
var running = true;
var cid = process.env.cid;

process.on("message", function(data){
    data = (data + "").trim().toLowerCase();
    process.send("Child process " + data);
});

process.send({cid: cid, msg: "Child process " + cid + " running"});

while(running){

}

process.send("Child stopped!");
```

I am starting the child like so:

```
var children = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    children[i] = cp.fork("./child.js", [], {
//        silent: true,
        cwd: __dirname,
        env: {
            cid: i
        }
    });
    children[i].on("message", function(msg){
        console.log("Message from " + msg.cid + ": " + msg.msg);
    });
}
```

I am then sending a message like this:

```
for(var i in children){
    console.log("    Sending message to child " + i);
    children[i].send("msg");
}
```

When I run `server.js` I get this output:

```
Message from 1: Child process 1 running
Message from 0: Child process 0 running
Message from 2: Child process 2 running
Message from 3: Child process 3 running
Message from 4: Child process 4 running
    Sending message to child 0
    Sending message to child 1
    Sending message to child 2
    Sending message to child 3
    Sending message to child 4
```

But they don't seem to be responding back with anything.

I am getting no error, and no output from the child process. What is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the infinite while loop, the childs should not exit while there are active event listeners, unless you explicitly call `process.exit()`

Instead of telling the child process ended in the last line in a procedural style, use an event style on exit:

```
process.on('exit', function(code) {
    process.send("Child stopped!");
});
```

[**process** docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html)

[**ChildProcess** docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

As events are only handled when the process is idle, as javascript does not implement threads. Therefore a `while` loop will block the process, preventing it from receiving messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(running){

}
```

This block is the reason, it will run forever, and it will run as soon as the child is made, so child process would forever be struck in that loop with no time to handle the next line 
`process.send("Child stopped!");`  or the `process.on("message",...`

Comment: I want the process to run forever until the main process does a `send("stop")` to it to kill the process. Maybe there is a better way to make it run forever?

Comment: you have check your design, if I am correct, child process does run forver until someone explicitly kills it.

Comment: on a side note, if you have to wait for a flag, instead of while loop, rather use setInterval e.g. `var timer = setInterval(function(){
 if(!running) {
  process.send("Child stopped!");
  clearInterval(timer);
  process.exit();
 }
}, 100);`

Comment: looks like you are correct! it does run continuously without the loop! I can send messages to the children when I comment out the while loop! That is good info to know. Do these child processes exit when the main process stops?

Comment: do not have much idea about child process, but this might shed some light...https://www.exratione.com/2013/05/die-child-process-die/